# Nested For Loop for Subsetting Data in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am attempting to use a for loop to subset data into 30 datasets. Note, `pz`, and `scenario` are also columns in the dataset.

`pzs <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

`scenario <- list("Scenario_1", "Scenario_2", Scenario_3", "Scenario_4", "Scenario_5", "Scenario_6")`

`top_20 <- list()`

```
for(i in pzs){
   for(j in scenario){

   top_20[[i]][[j]] <- data %>%
                       filter(i == pz) %>%
                       filter(j == scenario) %>%
                       arrange(desc(sales)) %>%
                       head(n=10)
   }
 }
```

`

I get an error that says: `j == scenario` .. must be size 1, not size six. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share a sample data by [edit]ing your question and adding the output from `dput(head(data))` into a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: maybe try with : scenario <- c("Scenario_1", "Scenario_2", "Scenario_3", "Scenario_4", "Scenario_5", "Scenario_6")

Comment: That seems to have helped. Now I get the following error: Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: same for pzs: pzs <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: `data |> arrange(desc(sales)) |> slice(1:10, .by = c(pzs, scenario)) |> group_split(pzs, scenario)`?